# it allows publish app in huawei store with google purchase?

Tags: console, in-app-billing, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

I have app, which published in google play store an working nice. I want to publish this app in huawei store. but in my app I have in-app purchase with google billing. Is huawei allows publish app in them store ? Or I need to implement huawei purchase and then publish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google IAP will not work on HMS serviced devices. Because Google IAP needs Google id(GID). HMS devices cannot produce this ID. You need to integrate Huawei IAP into your project.